# Keep footer down with dynamic content

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, footer

I have dynamic content in a div called txtresults like this:

```
<div id="txtresults"></div>
```

This div is populated by html after a query is made with input value, please take a look at the example: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F9T7E/23/)

If you type something you will see the div getting populated by search results. My problem is that I want to position the footer (#footer) under the results no matter how long or short the results are. As you can see now the footer is positioned outside the #txtresults. If I place the footer inside the div I am ot able to see the div..How can I solve this?

Comment: oops , something went wrong in saving on JsFiddle....I have changed the link

Comment: Do you want to keep the footer on the bottom of the viewport when the results div is empty and the move it out of view if the results list gets longer?

Comment: please include code snippets in your question, to make it self contained.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there are no results, where do you want to have the footer?
From your question I interpret that you want a sticky footer.

Else if you want to have the footer just below your results, remove the `position: absolute` (and `bottom: 0`) from the `footer`.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the position absolute from the css then the footer will push down according to the content.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question right, you can simply **remove** the following from `#footer`:

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
```

You may also want to add a `margin-top: 20px` to the footer CSS.